# Is versionize a real word?

Tags: meaning, is-it-a-word, neologisms, derivational-morphology, productive-affixes

Is the word "versionize" a real word or is it a form of bastardization of English?

**Additional Info:**
I came across this word in a software feature tracker.  The feature called for something in the software to have the ability to save versions of it.  It went something like "*...Versionize feature X...*"

Interestingly, a lot of spell checkers seem to complain about the word too.

Comment: At the moment, it has no support and no dictionary has an entry for it.  In 5 years, who knows?

Comment: If _weaponize_ is a real word, then so is _versionize_. It's just that nobody needed a verb for it until very recently.

Comment: @JohnLawler, if you're ok with "*versionize*", how about "*editionize*"? "*Weaponize*" **is** a word, but what about "*shieldize*"? No one's used it yet, of course, but does that mean we shouldn't recognize it as a "real word"? If you're fine with "*shieldize*", how about "*shieldizeize*"? "*Shieldizeizeize*"? Bottom line: OP asked "is *versionize* a word?", so how do we know when something is *not* a word?

Comment: I wonder if it is just a sign of evolving times.  I added additional info about the context of the word where I found it.

Comment: It becomes a real word when real people start to accept it and use it in the real world. Sometimes this is to the dismay of many people, but that's how real language works.

Comment: @Jim Agreed wholeheartedly; the question is "how much" use is enough to establish a word as "real"? It's more than once, and it's less than 17 trillion times. There is some threshold. Question is: has "*versionize*" crossed that threshold? This reporter says no.

Comment: @DanBron I have shown the clear path, grasshopper, but I have said the path is not clear. Others will decide.

Comment: Be warned that allegations of bastardy remain fightin’ words in many parts of the world.

Comment: I've realised that a tChrist points out, the "many people are using it" aspect is irrelevant.  Unfingered and fingerize are both, in fact, real words - end of story. They both have absolutely perfectly defined meanings, and are both in (via the prefix/suffix) the OED.  It's likely both have never been typed or said before, but that does't matter.  Prefix/Suffis use is like that.

Comment: I think we need to have a higher standard for *real*, using the definition of something *genuine* and *practical* and *deserving* not merely *existing*.  I type a word and then ask 'is it real/existing?' makes no sense. It exists because I typed it.  But is it genuine & practical & deserving like when we talk about *real* success or *real* friendship or when the IRS wants to know if a home charity is *real*?  Using the *it can exist* standard is a cop-out response to a very complex question.

Comment: How would 'version' and 'versioned', written as verbs, (*I versioned all the amendments to date*) differ from 'versionize* and *versionized*. In the same vein I fail to see the distinction between a *reverential* attitude to something, and a *reverent* one.

Comment: @WS2 words don't have to differ in meaning to exist, though once they have existed long enough separately they will probably acquire distinctions in connotation if not denotation.

Comment: @JoeBlow Only *productive* suffixes/prefixes though. Many affixes in English are not currently productive in derivation.

Comment: *...the ability to save versions of [the software].* FWIW, using that ability is sometimes called ***versioning***: exercising the ability to create (and then delete, compare, patch, save, track, & otherwise manipulate) different versions of a file or program or software feature...  To my mind, *versionizing* is creating the ability to have versions where that ability did not exist, whereas *versioning* is exercising that ability, i.e., creating versions. IOW, I think you versionize a given software product only once: giving it version control. From then on you version it (or its components).

Comment: @DanBron - *It's just that nobody needed a verb for it until very recently.*  You're saying we need one now??

Comment: @HotLicks, think you meant to direct that question to John Lawler. I certainly don't think we need any such word as "versionize"! (BTW, how did you come across this old question?)

Comment: @DanBron - Oops!! Yep, wrong @ person.  (And tchrist edited his response, resurrecting the zombie.)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## *Whateverize* is always a word

Yes, of course *versionize* is a “real word” — and no disparaging remarks about its parentage should be made in polite company.

This is because *‑ize* is a [*productive suffix*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Productivity_(linguistics)) in English that’s used to produce a new verb from various nouns and adjectives.  That means that any word derived by combining an existing one of those using *‑ize* is <sub><sup>**AUTOMATICALLY**</sup></sub> also a “real word”.

This remains true under all conditions:

- The result is still a “real word” even if you cannot find that word in any dictionary howsoever complete, abstruse, current, or hip said dictionary should happen to be.
- The result is still a “real word”  even if Google despite its omniscience cannot find that word anywhere.
- The result is still a “real word” even if nobody but nobody in the entire world has ever before used that word.  This particular sort of production is one that happens every day; it’s called making a <sub><sup>**NONCE-WORD**</sup></sub>.  They’re one-shot words that are used once only as the need arises and then put back in the cupboard, perhaps never to be seen again. The OED lists many such nonce-words, including *pedestrianize, cricketize, Londonize, Klondykize*, and even *Joe-Millerize*, plus many more besides.

Indeed, **the OED specifically states that such nonce-words are *“WITHOUT LIMIT”***, and that means there really and truly are infinitely many of them.

It cannot be made plainer than that, for something that is without limit cannot be limited — it is illimitable. Such *‑ize* derivations know no bound, for *-ize* is an infinite font of new words, a spring that can never run dry.

In fact, given an *‑ize* word, no matter whether of ancient provenance like *baptize* or a nonce-word like *Joe-Millerize*, a whole slew of other “real words” automatically derive from that.  The OED specifically notes that this occurs when it says under its entry for *‑ize*:

> Verbs in *-ize*
>   have the usual derivative adjs. and sbs., as ppl. adj. in *-ed*
>   (often more used than the vb.) as ‘sensitized paper’; ppl. adj. in
>   *-ing*, chiefly from the intrans. use, as ‘Judaizing Christians’,
>   ‘a philosophizing writer’; vbl. sb. in *-ing*, as ‘the
>   Bowdlerizing of Shakspere’; agent-noun in *-izer* (sometimes
>   coexistent with a formation on the Greek type in <sub><sup>**-IST**</sup></sub>), as *colonizer*
>   (*colonist*); noun of action in *-ization* (sometimes
>   coexistent with one from Gr. in <sub><sup>**-ISM**</sup></sub>), as
>   *civilization*, *organization* (*organism*).

Hence:

- *baptize, baptized, baptizing, baptizer,* †*baptization* 

  <sub>That ‘†’ up there prefixing the last word on the previous line is how the OED erects a memorial cross over the grave of a word that has shuffled off this mortal coil: one that’s now considered obsolete. *Baptization* is an example of a “real word” that failed to remained current, probably due to competition with *baptism*.  It is unlikely that many tears were shed at its funeral.</sub>
- *versionize, versionized, versionizing, versionizer, versionization*
- *Londonize, Londonized, Londonizing, Londonizer, Londonization*
- *Joe-Millerize, Joe-Millerized, Joe-Millerizing, Joe-Millerizer, Joe-Millerization*

When duly applied to existing words of the applicable type, productive affixes <sub><sup>**ALWAYS**</sup></sub> produce “real words”, for thus is the nature of productivity: it is inherently productive.

Aesthetics, however, is something else altogether.

---

### It is *always* still a word — even if you don’t like it!

In other words, it behaves exactly like how anything derived from existing words using productive affixes like *‑ly*,  *‑able*,  *un-*, and *pre-* is also automatically a “real word”.

Unlike little-known Greek affixes like *achroö-* or *-dactyl* but more like *pseudo-* or *‑cracy*, the *‑ize* suffix has been sufficiently naturalized in English that any native speaker can be expected to know exactly what is meant by any new word derived using it, not just specialists and Hellenists alone.

Mind you, just because anyone anywhere will automatically understand it does not necessarily mean that they will <sub><sup>**LIKE**</sup></sub> it.

Indeed, words created in this way are often heavily stigmatized, especially if they are then subsequently [nominalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalization) using the  *‑ation* suffix. It might well be better to start over instead of going from a noun to a verb and back to a noun again.

One criticism of such words is that they tend to occur in documents produced by organizations known for impenetrably turgid prose. But complaining of their turgidity or boisterousness is a different criticism altogether. And it’s hardly a new complaint either: see the Nashe citation from 1591 below, and you will realize that people have been gnashing their teeth as this tired old chestnut for more than four centuries.

These sorts of derived words are also criticized as being unnecessary when a simpler and perfectly suitable word or short phrase already exists, such as we see with *incentivize* being tut-tutted as a clumsy alternative for *motivate* or *give an incentive*.

Government documents and business jargon are both notorious for this sort of obfuscatory cant.  That’s why so many of the entries on Forbes’ famous list of [The Most Annoying, Pretentious And Useless Business Jargon](http://www.forbes.com/sites/groupthink/2012/01/26/the-most-annoying-pretentious-and-useless-business-jargon/) are words created through these same processes.   *Refactor* looks fancier and more self-important than *rewrite* or *redesign*, just as *reify* looks way more high-falutin’ than *create*, *realize*, or *thingify* ever can.

Or so the theory goes.   Whatever the reason,  we too often get a muddled mess out of such organizations instead of getting plain English. So complaints like those are not wholly ungrounded.

But that still has nothing to do with whether it is a “real word”. Of course it is.  It <sub><sup>**HAS**</sup></sub> to be, because that’s how <sub><sup>**PRODUCTIVE**</sup></sub> affixes work: they <sub><sup>**PRODUCE**</sup></sub> words.

---

### Quoth the OED

Here is the OED’s ***unstigmaticized*** description of the *‑ize* suffix:

> ## *-ize*, also written *-ise*
>
> suffix forming vbs. = F. *-ise-r*, It. *-izare*, Sp.
>   *-izar*, ad. late L. *-izāre*, *-īzāre*, f. Gr.
>   *-ίζειν*, formative derivative of vbs.
>
> > The Greek
> >   verbs were partly intrans., as *βαρβαρίζειν* to play the
> >   barbarian, act or speak as a barbarian, side with the barbarians,
> >   *τυραννίζειν* to side with the tyrants, partly trans. as
> >   *καθαρίζειν* to purify, clean, *θήσαυρίζειν* to treasure
> >   up. 
> >  Those formed on national, sectarian, or personal names were
> >   primarily intransitive, as *Ἀττικίζειν* to Atticize in manners,
> >   to speak Attic, *Φιλιππίζειν* to act or speak for Philip, to
> >   philippize, *Ἑλληνίζειν* to ‘do’ the Greek, act as a Greek,
> >   speak Greek, Hellenize; also, to make Greek. A few words of this
> >   form connected with or used in early Christianity, were latinized
> >   already in the 3rd or 4th c. by Christian writers: such were
> >   *βαπτίζειν* *baptizāre*, *εὐαγγελίζειν* *euangelizāre*,
> >   *κατηχίζειν* *catechizāre*, *σκανδαλίζειν*
> >   *scandalizāre*, *ἀναθηματίζειν* *anathēmatizāre*,
> >   *χριστιανίζειν* *christiānizāre*, *ἰουδαίζειν*
> >   *iūdaizāre*. Others continued to be formed both in ecclesiastical
> >   and philosophical use, e.g. *canōnizāre*, *dæmonizāre*,
> >   *syllogizāre* (Boethius *Aristot. Anal*.); and this became
> >   established as the normal form for the latinizing of Greek verbs,
> >   or the formation of verbs upon Greek analogies.
> >  In med.L. and the
> >   mod. langs. these have been formed also on L. or modern national
> >   names, and the use has been extended to the formation of verbs from
> >   L. adjs. or sbs. This practice prob. began first in French; in
> >   mod.F. the suffix has become *-iser*, alike in words from
> >   Greek, as *baptiser*, *évangéliser*, *organiser*,
> >   and those formed after them from L., as *civiliser*,
> >   *cicatriser*, *humaniser*. Hence, some have used the
> >   spelling *-ise* in Eng., as in French, for all these words,
> >   and some prefer *-ise* in words formed in French or Eng. from
> >   L. elements, retaining *-ize* for those of Gr. composition.
> >   
> >  But the suffix itself, whatever the element to which it is added,
> >   is in its origin the Gr. *-ιζειν*, L. *-izāre*; and, as
> >   the pronunciation is also with *z*, there is no reason why in
> >   English the special French spelling should be followed, in opposition
> >   to that which is at once etymological and phonetic. In this Dictionary
> >   the termination is uniformly written *-ize*. (In the Gr.
> >   *-ιζ-*, the *i* was short, so originally in L., but the
> >   double consonant *z* (= <sub><sup>**DZ**</sup></sub>, <sub><sup>**TS**</sup></sub>) made the
> >   *syllable* long; when the *z* became a simple consonant,
> >   *-i*dz became *īz*, whence Eng. /-aɪz/.)
>
> In current English the following groups may be noted:
>
> **1.**
>   Words that have come down from Greek, or have been at some time adopted from Greek, or formed on Greek elements; **a.** with the
>   trans. sense of ‘make or conform to, or treat in the way of, the thing expressed by the derivation’, as *baptize* (prob. the
>   earliest *-ize* word in Eng.), *anathematize*, *anatomize*,
>   *apostrophize*, *canonize*, *catechize*, *cauterize*,
>   *characterize*, *christianize*, *crystallize*, 
>   *diphthongize*, *harmonize*, *idolize*, *monopolize*,
>   *organize*, *phlebotomize*, *stigmatize*, *symbolize*,*systematize*, *tantalize*; **b.** with the intrans.
>   sense ‘to act some person or character, do or follow some practice’, 
>   as *agonize*, *apologize*, *apostatize*, *botanize*,
>   *dogmatize*, *geologize*, *philosophize*, *syllogize*,
>   *sympathize*, *theorize*.
>
> **2.** Words formed (in
>   Fr. or Eng.) on Latin adjs. and sbs. (esp. on derivative adjs. in
>   *-al*, *-ar*, *-an*, etc.), mostly with the trans.
>   sense ‘to make (that which is expressed by the derivation)’, as 
>   *actualize*, *authorize*, *brutalize*, *civilize*,
>   *colonize*, *consonantize*, *devocalize*, *eternize*,
>   *etherealize*, *familiarize*, *fertilize*,
>   *formalize*, *fossilize*, *humanize*, *immortalize*,
>   *legalize*, *memorize*, *nationalize*, *naturalize*,
>   *neutralize*, *patronize*, *pulverize*, *realize*,
>   *satirize*, *scrutinize*, *secularize*, *signalize*,
>   *solemnize*, *spiritualize*, *sterilize*, *terrorize*,
>   *vocalize*; trans. or intrans., as *cicatrize*,
>   *extemporize*, *moralize*, *particularize*; less
>   frequently only intrans., as *temporize*.
>
> **3.** Words
>   from later sources, as *bastardize*, *foreignize*,
>   *jeopardize*, *villanize*, *womanize* trans.,
>   *gormandize*, and such nonce-words as *cricketize*,
>   *pedestrianize*, *tandemize*, intr.
>
> **4.** Words
>   formed on ethnic adjs., and the like, chiefly trans. but sometimes
>   intrans., as *Americanize*, *Anglicize*, *Gallicize*,
>   *Germanize*, *Latinize*, *Romanize*, *Russianize*.
>
> **5.** Words formed on names of persons, sometimes with the
>   intrans. Greek sense of ‘to act like, or in accordance with’, as
>   in *Calvinize*, *Coryatize*, but usually in the trans.
>   sense of ‘to treat like, or after the method of, or according to
>   the (chemical or other) process of’; as in *Boucherize*,
>   *Bowdlerize*, *Burnettize*, *galvanize*, *Grangerize*,
>   *macadamize*, *mesmerize*, *Rumfordize*; with many
>   technical and commercial terms, and nonce-words such as *Gladstonize*,
>   *Irvingize*, *Joe Millerize*, *Merry-Andrewize*,
>   ***without limit***.
>
> **6.** From names of substances, chemical and
>   other; in the trans. sense of ‘to charge, impregnate, treat, affect,
>   or influence with’; as *alcoholize*, *alkalize*,
>   *carbonize*, *de-oxidize*, *hydrogenize*, *oxidize*,
>   *ozonize*, *silverize*, etc.; so in nonce-words, as
>   *Londonize* to make like London, etc.
>
> Verbs in *-ize*
>   have the usual derivative adjs. and sbs., as ppl. adj. in *-ed*
>   (often more used than the vb.) as ‘sensitized paper’; ppl. adj. in
>   *-ing*, chiefly from the intrans. use, as ‘Judaizing Christians’,
>   ‘a philosophizing writer’; vbl. sb. in *-ing*, as ‘the
>   Bowdlerizing of Shakspere’; agent-noun in *-izer* (sometimes
>   coexistent with a formation on the Greek type in <sub><sup>**-IST**</sup></sub>), as *colonizer*
>   (*colonist*); noun of action in *-ization* (sometimes
>   coexistent with one from Gr. in <sub><sup>**-IST**</sup></sub>), as
>   *civilization*, *organization* (*organism*).

### Hey, if you think *versionize* is bad. . . .

Anyone who lifts a supercilious eyebrow at the notion of *versionize* as a “real word” should pay especial attention to the rich — some might say outlandish — examples provided by the OED in its citations for *‑ize*, because quite frankly I think you will astonished at some of these, which I have placed in **bold** to help guie your eye to their awesomeness:

> The
>   following are illustrations of some of the recent uses of the suffix:
>
> - **1591** Nashe *Introd. Sidney’s
>     Astr. & Stella* in *P. Penilesse* (Shaks. Soc.) p. xxx,
>     ― Reprehenders, that complain of my boystrous compound wordes, and
>     ending my Italionate coyned verbes all in *ize*.
>
>   **1611** Florio, ― *Inpetrarcato*,
>     **Petrarchized**.
>
>   **1618** J. Taylor (Water
>     P.) *Journ. Scotl.*, ― I haue a smacke of **Coriatizing**.
>
>   **1682** D’Urfey *Butler’s Ghost* II.
>     177 ― Ralpho··takes the Tongs··and snaps him by the Nose··surpriz’d,
>     To be thus rudely **dunstaniz’d**.
>
>   **1796**
>     Coleridge *Lett.* I. 209 ― We might **Rumfordize** one
>     of the chimneys.
>
>   **1833** *Blackw. Mag.*
>     XXXIV. 533 ― It is a taste that, to coin a word, **insignificantizes**
>     everything-**unpoetizes** nature.
>
>   **1840** *New
>     Monthly Mag.* LIX. 492 ― **Tandemizing, cricketizing, boatizing**,
>     *et omne quod exit in* izing, is not to be carried on without
>     a considerable expenditure.
>
>   **1858** *Sat.
>     Rev.* V. 264/2 ― He has no fear of **Tower-Hamletizing** the land.
>
>   **1858** *Sat. Rev.* VI. 203/2 ― To **Perkin-Warbeckize**
>     a pretender is the best, because not the most spirited, policy.
>
>   **1861** T. L. Peacock *Gryll Gr.*
>     viii, ― Arch-quacks have taken to **merry‐andrewizing** in a new arena.
>
>   **1866** *Sat. Rev.* 10 Nov. (L.), ― If a
>     man··is funny, and succeeds in **Joe-Millerizing** history, he pleases
>     somebody or other.
>
>   **1876** Preece &
>     Sivewright *Telegraphy* 164 ― Of the first class
>     [Preservation of Timber] the three best known processes are: (a)
>     **Burnetising**, (b) **Kyanising**, and (c) **Boucherising**.
>
>   **1881**
>     Mahaffy in *Academy* 23 Apr. 295 ― She does not
>     **Irvingise** Shylock.
>
>   **1885** Jeaffreson
>     *Real Shelley* II. 192 ― The troop of **nakedized** children rushed
>     downstairs.
>
>   **1894** *Westm. Gaz.* 21 Mar.
>     7/3 ― These instruments, before they are used, should always be
>     strictly **anti-septicized**.
>
>   **1897** A. Lang
>     in *Blackw. Mag.* Feb. 187 ― To do this is not to **Celticise**
>     but to Macphersonise.
>
>   **1897** *Westm. Gaz.*
>     28 July 6/1 ― The word ‘**Klondykised**’ has been coined to express the
>     conditions of persons who have caught the mania [for seeking gold
>     at Klondyke]... The effect has been to ‘**Klondykise**’ nearly all the
>     people of the town.
>
>   **1898** L. A. Tollemache
>     *Talks w. Gladstone* 114 *note*, ― It [the passage] is,
>     as it were, Canning **Gladstonized**.

Yup, that’s right; you really did just read about “*nakedized* children”.

As you can see, we’ve gone minting new  words using this suffix for centuries and centuries, and little ol’ *versionize* is utterly unexceptionable compared with many you’ve just read above.

In fact, it’s downright boring, so much so that you might even say, as the citations suggest, that it has been *insignificantized* by all those others.   
<sub>(And yes, I can hear you all groaning out there, but it’s right there in print ever since way back in 1833, for goodness’ sake!)</sub>

Nifty, eh? That’s productivity for you!  Surely *‑ize* is as fecund a suffix as you can imagine, maybe even more fecund than you <sub><sup>**WANT**</sup></sub> to imagine. :)

---

## Summary

So yeah, *versionize* is a “real word” — and in fact, it <sub><sup>**HAS**</sup></sub> to be.

But you certainly don’t have to like it if you don’t want to.  Just don’t go expecting everybody else in the whole world to share your own peculiar likes and dislikes.

Indeed, it’s probably better if you expect that they won’t share them. By setting your expectations appropriately, you will make life a great deal easier on yourself — and on others.

---

#### *Postscript*

Although some folks may find certain combinations and applications ugly and perhaps even awkward, one should <sub><sup>**NEVER**</sup></sub> accuse someone of making bastards: it is not only impolite, it might be downright dangerous.

In other words, if linguists don’t talk about “bastardizing” language, perhaps no one else should be doing that either.

For that matter, you might also want to tread lightly when it comes to “real words”.

Comment: It **has** to be?  Are you sure *ize* justifizes every word we attach it to?

Comment: @DanBron “Justifies”? I have no idea; that sounds like asking me whether it’s a good idea, and you have to make that decision for yourself.  But makes it “a real word”?  Yup, quite sure. As I explain at length and with references, that is the nature of derivational morphology as applied to productive affixes. But I have no expectation that all such derivationalizations will be well-loved.  Certainly there is no love lost between me and many that I read.

Comment: I realize you answerized and your contribution was well referencized, but I can't help but wonderfy whether a word must be well recognized to be legitimized or any string of letters -- properly morphologized, of course -- can be characterized as English.

Comment: As @tchrist knows, the whole "is it a real word" question is tied up with prescriptivism. If you're a strict prescriptivist, it's not a real word. If you're not a strict prescriptivist, it is a real word as long as it conveys a meaning rather like what is intended by the user to the listener.

Comment: Ah, but someone deleted those comments. They're lostified.

Comment: You tchristized the heck out of this answer. I'd give more pluses, but all I have is 1.

Comment: @Dan lostifized because I felt the remaining comments summarized the rest sufficiently.

Comment: I fail to see how 'Productivity is, as stated above and implied in the examples already discussed, a matter of degree' (in the Wikipedia link) can coexist with 'Productive affixes always — always, always, always — create “real words”, for thus is the nature of productivity.'

Comment: I like how people are trying to make your answer look silly by making verbs out of words that shouldn't be verbs in the context they are using them and then saying "look, it's ridiculous to use a verb there".

Comment: "By definition" doesn't mean what you think it means. "Whateverize" is a word by construction. For it to be a word by definition, the definition of "word" would have to include something like "anything ending in -ize is a word".

Comment: @DavidRicherby - This punctuates the point, differently I think.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It means that if you follow the rules for deriving a new word from a productive suffix, it is also a word. Productive means you get to use it to make new words that are understandable without requiring a dictionary dive to figure them out.  Try it with *un-* or *sub-* or *-able* or *-ly*, for example.  Sure, there are invalid productions, but that is because each has its own little set of subrules. Follow those rules and you can be fairly sure you’ve made a word; it just might have unfortunate connotations or uncomfortable sounds.

Comment: But look at category 5. Words formed on names of persons, sometimes with the intrans. Greek sense of ‘to act like, or in accordance with’, as in Calvinize, Coryatize, but usually in the trans. sense of ‘to treat like, or after the method of, or according to the (chemical or other) process of’; as in Boucherize, Bowdlerize. Let's say someone comes up with 'Wagnerise'. How can a reader know what the coiner means? A free-for-all may appeal to libertines, but the language deserves better.

Comment: Is it still a real word if the base word is NOT a noun or adjective, though? You answered this in the comments but the answer proper still insists that any derivation using this suffix is a word, despite also giving specific criteria for when this is so.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The reader can know the same way a skilled reader would know (or guess near enough to continue reading without consulting a dictionary right then and there) the meaning of any unknown word encountered in context: By inferring from the context, and the additional clues provided by the name and the suffix.

Comment: This answer is biased because it is based on a selective (and I'd say unwarranted) underlying definition of the terms 'word' and 'productive'.

Comment: If you want to discuss this answer, please take it to chat.

Answer (score 2):

This word appears to be jargon (ie technical terminology) in the computer programming and administration fields.

[wordnik.com](https://www.wordnik.com/words/versionize) provides "To make a version of; translate." which it attributes to The Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia.

This 2012 [blog](http://boblu.com/2012/03/how-do-you-versionize-your-code/) is entitled "How Do You Versionize Your Code?" which uses *versionize* in context of keeping different versions of in progress work so that one can return to an earlier version if some error is found in the current version.  It refers to *versionizing tools* as well as the ability to *versionize* without using these tools.

A Dec 2011 [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/370603/how-to-archive-and-versionize-a-filesystem-for-windows-and-macosx) question asks for help in "How to archive and versionize a filesystem for Windows and MacOSX?"

So, recognizing that the word is jargon, that leads us directly to the debate of whether we should consider jargon to be a "a real word or ... a ... bastardization".  In framing that debate this [article](http://www.pathguy.com/Orwellroney.pdf) may be useful.  Orwell and many others, it seems, would probably say "bastardization" while Judith Butler (who the article says won the annual 'Bad Writing Award' from the journal of Philosophy and Literature) and others would probably say it's a "real word".

Probably only the future knows if this particular word will one day become commonly accepted language (beyond it's current technical area), as many words that started as jargon have, or will eventually fade and be forgotten, as has been the fate of many other words that started as jargon.

Comment: A largely beautiful answer.  Anyone who writes "When framing the debate.." is a master of nuance.

Comment: For those uses, the **vastly** more common usage is "Version" or "Version Control". Google Ngram viewer has no hits on "versionize" or "versionizing"; a Google web search for "versionize" has ~8,000 hits vs. 2 million for "version control".

Answer (score 2):

Sure, "versionize" is utterly common in computing-marketing.

(Self-evidently, it just means, to convert a fairly undynamic, unsupported product (perhaps an app), to one that has supported regularly ongoing versions.  It's just like "monetise."

Another similar trendy term today is **"gamification"** (or perhaps gamization).

Questions about "real words" are annoying.  The concept "real word" is meaningless, and presupposes there is some authority or platonic .. decision .. about "words". There is no such authority or platonic, um, epistemological duality.

Comment: "Epistemological duality", Joe, really? ;)  In re: your answer, I've personally never heard "versionize" before, and I've been in computers (and, sadly, marketing) my whole career.  Can you dig up a good swath of quotes or references? I'd +1 if you can support that the word really is widespread.

Comment: I'm sorry; I could't be bothered.  (If you assert I'm wrong and it is not widespread in <whatever it is you check that in>, I completely believe you.)  You know, do you work with, as they say "apps" -- perhaps it's a bit of an "appized" thing. (Like monetize, you know?) I just found eleven hits in my email for instance. (Tragically some of my concerns work with "apps", but don't shoot me.)

Comment: Maybe it's a UK thing.  Anyway, if you've found 11 instances in your actual email, that's good enough for me.

Comment: Never heard that "self-evident" meaning in ~15 years. Most of the hits found by Google show it being used to refer to version control (and that was my first thought on seeing the question).

Comment: @DanBron As a UK person in a technological field, I've never heard "versionize".

Comment: I'd have guessed 'versionize' to mean 'to make different versions' (eg for academic bodies, the general public, Junior School children ...)

Comment: fascinating, Edwin - that makes perfect sense.

Comment: ... Perhaps the definition 'making up not-even-pseudowords because that's what we are allowed to do in real English' might fit 'perversionise'.

Answer (score 0):

The only source available seems to be the following , [versionize](https://www.wordnik.com/words/versionize):

> - To make a version of; translate.

Source: The Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia

I think that *to make a version*  is the expression to use.

Considering the additional information in your question, a check  with  [google](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=versionize&word2=save%20a%20version) shows a very limited use of '*versionize*' ( or versionise) compared to  '*save a version*'. Maybe the neologism will gain currency in the future.

Comment: @JoeBlow If you want to retract a comment, delete it. There's a little `x' icon after the posting time of your own comments.

Comment: Hi David! Funny you mention that: it drives me nuts when people "fail to" delete comments or edit posts. I always just delete any comments I have made, which proved to be Totally Wrong or I was drunk at the time.  In this case I just didn't want to make your comment confusing.  Cheers