# Word for "to make italic"?

Tags: single-word-requests

When we make text **bold**, we can just use the verb "bold".

When we make text underlined, we can use the verb "underline".

But which verb would we use for making text *italic*?

Comment: [Tangentially related](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/192779).

Comment: You must have been emboldened to use bold as a verb. In such circumstances I would be inclined to *slope* off, which is what computer applications tend to do when they do not have access to properly italicized fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're thinking of the word [*italicize*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/italicize) (can be spelt with an *S* instead of *Z*).

For instance, I italicized the word 'italicize' in that sentence.

Comment: Instead of “You're thinking of...”, it might be more accurate to say “You're *not* thinking of...”