# Is majoritively a word?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, adverbs, is-it-a-word

So I was writing a sentence and the word ***majoritively*** popped into my head as a "Hey, why not? Sounds good!" type of word.

My sentence was to the effect of:

*Our GridViews **majoritively** use classic bindings from the its ItemsSource property which is usually bound to an ObservableCollection of an entity data object, where then each GridViewColumn is bound to its respective (or matching) entity data object property.*

*<sub>Note: This sentence contains words that are control names.</sub>*

---

**I know I can switch the sentence around to use** "The majority of the time".  
**I was just curious about the specific word.**

Comment: Google Books [claims 38 instances of the word](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Majoritively%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22Majoritively%22&tbm=bks&start=30). But that's in over 20M books, so I'd be inclined to dismiss that handful as "ignorant errors".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Hmm ... your statement of "ignorant errors" would then conflict with [@FraserOrr's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/203476/60050).  Could you write answer that would expand further on why it *wouldn't* be considered an actual word?

Comment: Well, it's really just a matter of opinion, primarily based on how you define "a word". In total, there are obviously *billions* of words indexed by Google Books. This particular form (which is easily understood by anyone on first encounter) only occurs 38 times, *and* it doesn't appear in EOD. If Wiktionary were a paper-based publication we'd probably call it toilet paper, so an entry there doesn't really confer any "status". My *advice* is "Don't use it", but strictly speaking it's all Primarily Opinion-based, and therefore Off Topic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I agree with your assessment of Wiktionary =D. When you look it up at http://http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/majoritively it doesn't come up and that's usually my go-to.  So maybe you're right.  It's just opinion-based and should be closed?

Comment: My "knee-jerk" reaction is to think it would be good if we had a "canonical" question along the lines of *"What does **a valid word** mean?"*, so we could just closevote questions like yours here as duplicates. That wouldn't preclude people posting relevant *specific* points (such as mine above) as ***comments***. When it's a matter of closevoting with "Primarily Opinion-Based", I tend to hang back unless/until someone else does it first. (Maybe I *am* right that this one is POB - but that's just my opinion, after all! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Or maybe instead of asking if it's a word or not (since, if you can create a definition, it's a word regardless of whether or not it's recognized as one) I should re-title/re-word the question to ask whether it would be proper grammar to use the adverb, majoritively, in the way that I did. What do you think?

Comment: I obviously haven't made myself clear. Per my first comment, I consider it to be an "ignorant error", and per my second comment, my advice is **DON'T USE IT!** The intended *meaning* will be obvious to any native speaker, but they will also almost certainly understand an unwanted subtext (that you don't know English very well and/or you're making a fool of yourself by trying to use what you think are "posh" words).

Comment: Even if it is constructed according to reasonable use of English word formation patterns (over which I have my doubts), I still don't know what it is you want this to mean. You've used it in a sentence but you haven't given a plausible coherent meaning. I don't think anyone can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, *majoritively* is a word.  As one of our resident professional linguists so succinctly put it:

> ### [If you use the word when speaking English, then it is an English word.](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/1991/2085)

Now that that’s out of the way, what are we to make of the word *majoritively*? To start with, it comes from applying two common, productive suffixes to the existing word *majority*:

1. *-ive* converts a noun into a adjective or another noun
2. *-ly* converts an adjective into an adverb or a noun into an adjective

The second of those is incredibly productive; the first, somewhat less so,  although as *‑ative* it is fairly lively — just perhaps not quite so much as [*‑ize*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/192779/2085) is.

The OED tells us this about *-ive*:

> #### **-ive**, *suffix*, forming adjs. (and sbs.)
>
> Formerly also *‑if*, *‑ife*; a. Fr. *‑if*, fem. *‑ive* (= It., Sp. *-ivo*) :– L. *īv-us*, a suffix added to the ppl. stem of verbs,as in *act-īvus* active, *pass-īvus* passive, *nātīv-us* of inborn kind; sometimes to the pres. stem, as *cad-īvus* falling, andto sbs. as *tempest-īvus* seasonable. Few of these words came down in OF., e.g. *naïf*, *naïve* :– L. *nātīv-um*; but the suffix is largely used in the modern Romanic langs., and in Eng., to adapt L. words in *‑īvus*, or form words on L. analogies, with the sense ‘having a tendency to, having the nature, character, or quality of, given to (some action)’. The meaning differs from that of ppl. adjs. in
>   *‑ing*, *‑ant*, *‑ent*, in implying a permanent or habitual
>   quality or tendency: cf. <sub><sup>ACTING, ACTIVE, ATTRACTING, ATTRACTIVE,
>   COHERENT, COHESIVE, CONSEQUENT, CONSECUTIVE</sup></sub>. From their derivation, the great majority of these end in *‑sive* and
>   *‑tive*, and of these about one half in <sub><sup>‑ATIVE</sup></sub>,
>   which tends consequently to become a living suffix, as in *talk-ative*, etc. A few are formed immediately on the vb. stem, esp.
>   where this ends in *s* (*c*) or *t*, thus easily passing
>   muster among those formed on the ppl. stem; such are *amusive*,*coercive*, *conducive*, *crescive*, *forcive*,*piercive*, *adaptive*, *adoptive*, *denotive*,
>   *humective*; a few are from sbs., as *massive*. In
>   *costive*, the *‑ive* is not a suffix.
>
> Already in L. many of these adjs. were used subst.; this precedent is freely followed in the mod. langs. and in English: e.g. *adjective*,
>   *captive*, *derivative*, *expletive*, *explosive*,*fugitive*, *indicative*, *incentive*, *invective*,*locomotive*, *missive*, *native*, *nominative*,*prerogative*, *sedative*, *subjunctive*.
>
> In some words the final consonant of OF. *‑if*, from *‑īvus*, 
>   was lost in ME., leaving in mod.Eng. <sub><sup>-Y</sup></sub>: e.g. *hasty*,*jolly*, *tardy*.
>
> Adverbs from adjs. in *-ive* are formed in <sub><sup>‑IVELY</sup></sub>; 
>   abstract sbs. in ‑iveness and <sub><sup>‑IVITY</sup></sub> (F. *‑iveté*,
>   *‑ivité*, L. *‑īvitāt-em*), as in *activity*,
>   *conductivity*, *resistivity*, and similar terms; also
>   *spec.* (see quot. **1895**).

I’m a bit surprised you went for *majoritively* rather than *majoritatively*, in that *‑ative* tends to be the “living” (read: productive) version as explained above.

It’s so productive, it has its own entry:

> #### **‑ative**,
>
> ad. F. *‑atif*, *‑ative*, L. *‑ātīvus*,
>   consisting of adj. suffix *‑īvus* (see <sub><sup>‑IVE</sup></sub>)
>   appended to ppl. stems in *‑āt-* of vbs. in *‑āre*, e.g.
>   *dēmonstrāre* to point out, *dēmonstrāt-īvus* ‘having the
>   attribute or habit of pointing out, tending to point out.’ Only a few were
>   used in Latin, but the analogy is extensively followed in the modern
>   languages. In the majority of instances, as in *demonstrate*,
>   *demonstrative*, adjs. in *‑ative* belong to vbs. in *‑ate*;
>   cases like *represent*, *‑ative*, *affirm*, *‑ative*,
>   *figure*, *figurative*, in which the Eng. vb. represents (through
>   Fr.) the present stem of the Latin, have afforded a formal analogy for
>   *talk*, *talk-ative*.
>
> A few adjs. of this class are moreover formed directly from sbs. in
>   <sub><sup>‑TY</sup></sub>, as if from an intervening verb in *‑tate*,
>   which does not exist; e.g. <sub><sup>AUTHORITY</sup></sub>,
>   (**authoritate*), *authoritative*; so *qualitative*,
>   *quantitative*.

That’s why I was somewhat surprised that you didn’t just go from *majority* straight into *majoritatively*.  Some people do.  In fact, all these can be found in print:

- [majoritive](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22majoritive%22&btnG=Search&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) > [majoritively](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22majoritively%22&btnG=Search&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)
- [majoritative](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22majoritative%22&btnG=Search&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) > [majoritatively](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22majoritatively%22&btnG=Search&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

We can tell from the definitions of the suffixes what these words <sub><sup>**MUST**</sup></sub> mean.

There are only a few dozen instances of each found in Google Books, so it is not as though these were especially common words.  Even so, most citations are found in recent publications; they seem to have gained some traction in the 21<sup>st</sup> century.

I cannot say why that might be, but I will note that many books no longer go through the rigorous redaction process of draft, review, rewrite, copyedit, and proofread; it is possible that some of these might have been more felicitously phrased if they’d had a competent copyeditor to smooth out the wording.

In most instances, *majoritively* and *majoritatively* are used purely as synonyms for the simpler *mostly*.  However, in some cases, they take on a different nuance because they are specifically talking about some sort of majority being involved.

- The past and the future depend, **majoritively**, on sensations from physical stimuli  that deal with substance, content and contest of the physical situation, . . . [[*The Forbidden Gift*, Anttarr, 2007]](https://books.google.com/books?id=K2Z8uoj08iYC&pg=PA105&dq=%22majoritively%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RmuZVI3UOcqQyATE5YKgAw&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAA)
- Are the trammels of a third-rate, **majoritively** non-Christian, non-Muslim South-East Asian state not of the utmost inconsequence? [[*Perfect Hostage: A Life of Aung San Suu Kyi, Burma's Prisoner of Conscience*, Justin Wintle, 2007]](https://books.google.com/books?id=2QtK3PrF458C&pg=PA419&dq=%22majoritively%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RmuZVI3UOcqQyATE5YKgAw&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22majoritively%22&f=false)
- Level A, the lowest level, is 99 percent black, then level E, the highest, is only  eight percent, in a country that is **majoritively** black, where whites are a minority  and the equity act came in four years ago. [[*In Good Company: An Anatomy of Corporate Social Responsibility*, Dinah Rajak, 2011]](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22majoritively%22&btnG=Search&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)
- Yes, but that presumably decides from a number of options put to it by  various local authorities. In the end they do choose, **majoritively-wise**, a local  authority project. [[House of Commons, 1976]](https://books.google.com/books?id=fhg6AQAAIAAJ&q=%22majoritively%22&dq=%22majoritively%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=RmuZVI3UOcqQyATE5YKgAw&ved=0CFYQ6AEwDg)
- Compare this **majoritive** state of the proud and conceited intellect of man, with the  unproductive intellect of the technically-called insane, and say, if Shakspeare, in  seeing through the mind; commonly called the ‘heart’ of man; . . . [[*Analysis of the Human Intellect*, James Rush, 1865]](https://books.google.com/books?id=hGYAAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA422&dq=%22majoritive%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=O36ZVPKYO5KnyASnxoKgAw&ved=0CBYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22majoritive%22&f=false)
- **Majoritive** mandates serve as the standard of value which is destined to achieve  the twin objectives of political stability and the ‘utilitarian’ common good.  [[*Global Mining Investing*, Andrew Sheldon, 2014]](https://books.google.com/books?id=zbsYGZ0SYPgC&pg=PA190&dq=%22majoritive%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=O36ZVPKYO5KnyASnxoKgAw&ved=0CCcQ6AEwBA)
- We must not allow ourselves or our programmers to misuse the power with which  they have been entrusted by telling the public what it may or may not hear after  that public has legitimately substantiated and voiced its **majoritive** approval. [[*Tarnished Gold: The Record Industry Revisted*, R. Serge Denisoff, ‎1986]](https://books.google.com/books?id=JWdMOZGNOHUC&pg=PA281&dq=%22majoritive%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SYSZVNWgBcKdyATcsIKQAw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwBg)
- Still, it is equally uncontestable that the image rendered by Ms. Guy is hardly a  reflection of a whole and accurate, **majoritive**, image of male Afro-America. [[*Freedomways*, 1979]](https://books.google.com/books?id=LGa6AAAAIAAJ&q=%22majoritive%22&dq=%22majoritive%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=O36ZVPKYO5KnyASnxoKgAw&ved=0CGAQ6AEwEQ)
- A “suspect class” has a history of purposeful unequal treatment and needs  protection from the “**majoritive** political process.” [[*Proceedings of the NAPECW/NCPEAM National Conference*, National College Physical Education Association for Men (U.S.), 1978]](https://books.google.com/books?id=QxpPAAAAYAAJ&q=%22majoritive%22&dq=%22majoritive%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=O36ZVPKYO5KnyASnxoKgAw&ved=0CH4Q6AEwGA)
- In such a situation, society confronts a concretization quandary: there simply is no **majoritatively** acceptable way of reaching a **majoritatively** accepted goal.  [[*Complexity: A Philosophical Overview*,
  Nicholas Rescher, ‎1998]](https://books.google.com/books?id=OoLTggga2mMC&pg=PA187&dq=%22majoritatively%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FICZVLzzNor7yASWq4KoAw&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAw)
- However, the **majoritatively** entropic force driving protein folding cannot impart  any degree of selectivity to binding.  [[*Recognition Receptors in Biosensors*, 
  Mohammed Zourob, ‎2010]](https://books.google.com/books?id=qc7oM4yGwBEC&pg=PA465&dq=%22majoritatively%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FICZVLzzNor7yASWq4KoAw&ved=0CFoQ6AEwDg)
- Since as a practical matter juries may be **majoritatively** favorable to plaintiffs in  drug and device products liability litigation, epidemiologic testimony may be  impressive enough, in the absence of analytic guidelines from the judge, to sway  them ... [[*Pharmacoepidemiology*, Stanley Edlavitch, 1989]](https://books.google.com/books?id=ND5b6D0NcLcC&pg=PA78&dq=%22majoritatively%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FICZVLzzNor7yASWq4KoAw&ved=0CGQQ6AEwEA)
- Thirdly, that within a **majoritative** democracy, its government has a political  mandate, if not a positive responsibilty, to prioritise this claim over any competing  claims of its minorities. [[*The Twilight of Britain: Cultural Nationalism, Multiculturalism, and the Politics of Toleration*, G. Gordon Betts, 2002]](https://books.google.com/books?id=NUKTvzPrYZQC&pg=PA349&dq=%22majoritative%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=I4GZVP_SKtL_yQSyp4KgAw&ved=0CBQQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22majoritative%22&f=false)
- One of the primary concerns regarding the exercise of judicial review is that it is  **counter-majoritative**, allowing an unelected branch of government to determine  the validity of the actions of the elected, political branches of government. [[*Strategies for Success in Law School and Beyond*; Frank Read, Charles D. Cole, W. Scott Simpson; 2011]](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22majoritative%22&btnG=Search&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

So your instinct to derive this word using productive affixes is not original: other people have done the same thing, and a few of those even managed to find their way into print.

It is not a word that I myself would advise using; I think in almost all scenarios, a simpler wording is both possible and preferable. Much of the writing cited above is, I feel, a textbook example of how <sub><sup>**NOT**</sup></sub> to write — and just possibly, how <sub><sup>**NOT**</sup></sub> to derive new words without sounding risibly overbloviated.

But you really need to look at the in-print citations for yourself to see how these are being used by other people, and then decide for yourself whether you care for them or whether you might care to choose another way of expressing it.  Constantly piling on derivational affixes to create new words can be ugly.

Again, check these citations and see for yourself:

- [majoritive](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22majoritive%22&btnG=Search&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)
- [majoritively](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22majoritively%22&btnG=Search&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)
- [majoritative](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22majoritative%22&btnG=Search&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)
- [majoritatively](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22majoritatively%22&btnG=Search&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl)

Comment: 'majoritive' sounds wrong to me but 'majoritatively' sounds OK. Some suffixes work in some contexts some in others. But what does either actually _mean_?

Comment: @tchrist Very nice!  I never even thought about _majoritatively_. It makes much more sense to me now. Thanks.

Comment: M-W's Usage Discussion of _irregardless_: 
Irregardless originated in dialectal American speech in the early 20th century. Its fairly widespread use in speech called it to the attention of usage commentators as early as 1927. The most frequently repeated remark about it is that “there is no such word.” There is such a word, however. It is still used primarily in speech, although it can be found from time to time in edited prose. Its reputation has not risen over the years, and it is still a long way from general acceptance. Use regardless instead. >> ...

Comment: It would be nice to have a term for an 'acceptable word'. 'Word', perhaps.

Comment: But what does 'majoritatively' or 'majoritively' _mean_? (and does that meaning come from these word formation patterns).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, see:

[Wiktionary: Majoritively](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/majoritively)

> By means of a majority.
>   (proscribed) Consisting of more than half (50%); predominantly.

However, it certainly isn't a common word, and honestly, I don't see that it fits well in the example you gave. You might instead choose "usually", "frequently", "commonly" or "most often" instead.

Comment: Yea ... I saw that prior to posting, but was wanting some more expert advice.  I don't usually trust any wiki-type site without further research to back up what's said in there.

Answer (score 2):

*Majority* is overused, anyway.  Best to restrict it to matters of voting.

Usually, the word *most* works just fine.  Instead of *majoritatively*, use *mostly*.

Comment: Mostly is definitely a more proper word for sure, but I like going against the grain, though, that's why I'm a maverick! Or ... as my daughter calls me, a hipster, because I am usually onto things first and then turn on them when they become popular ... LoL! I also like to expand my vocabulary and not always stick with the most common, dull routes. That's why I was just checking to see if it was really a word or not.

Answer (score 0):

I refuse to believe 'majoritively' is a word when it doesn't exist in the OERD. You can use majority quite easily. Why not just use, "The majority of our GridViews'?

-ive = in the nature of. How can you be in the nature of a majority?

-ly = does indeed describe the quality of a thing, but so does -ty.

Why have we suddenly started making words up that not only make no sense, but also confuse people's established understanding of the word? Simplify don't confuse.

Comment: Good points for sure.

Comment: Sorry CM, but I just joined because this question irritated me so much I had to respond. I know nothing of this point system of which you speak. But thanks :)

Comment: No worries. All viewpoints are considered. The reason I asked the question originally was that, often times, words just pop into my head that aren't of the ordinary ilk. Simply for curiosity's sake.

Comment: It's cool CM. I do the same sometimes, but it's much easier to go the simpler route, for yourself and whoever is reading your work.

Answer (score 0):

“Almost all of these schools are majority white—in fact, black men make up only 2.4 percent of the total undergraduate population of the 65 schools in the so-called Power Five athletic conferences.”

“Presented with a choice between Clemson and North Carolina A&T, most high-school athletes would choose Clemson—whose starting lineup, not incidentally, is majority black.”

"The flight of black athletes to majority-white colleges has been devastating to HBCUs."

I saw these lines in an article and it doesn't seem right. But Websters doesn't have an adjective for majority... I cannot find majoritively or majoritatively.

https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/2019/10/black-athletes-should-leave-white-colleges/596629/

Comment: I'm not sure how your examples sentences relate to the existence of majoritively as a word. Demonstrating that majority is used doesn't prove or disprove the usage of majoritively.

Comment: These were sentences I saw in print and felt majoirty had been used incorrectly.  I was asking if it should have been written using majorititvely instead of majority. Majority, a noun, in this sample is being used as an adjective. But Webster's doesn't have majoritively or majoritatively as words.