# French (and, hey, others too) equivalent of "anglicize"

Tags: translation, hypernyms, loanwords, anglicization

Is there a preferred word that means "to change (a word) to sound (or otherwise appear) as if it came from French"? I've found both "Frenchize" and "Francize" with a web search. If the latter is preferred, I'm not sure whether it takes a soft "C".

Come to think of it, the same could be asked of any language. It would be interesting to have a list like this.

Even more interesting would be to have a general term for the conversion (possibly surreptitious, as of a surname) from one language to another.

---

Edit: Here's a list of whatever we come up with.

English → *Anglicize*
French → *Gallicize*
German → *Germanize*
Greek → *Grecize*

Comment: Anglicize means to bring it into English, so are you looking for the word to bring something into French?  Wouldn't that word be French?

Comment: Heh. I suppose it would. But I imagine you can translate the word "anglicize" into French, so maybe you can do the reverse too.

Comment: Except this is an site for English language usage so I wouldn't be inclined to do that - although I think Brian Donovan may be on to something with his answer! :-)

Comment: Perhaps a gallicized version of *germanizing* might be *allemandation,* but I suspect the change would be for the Wurst ;-)

Comment: Things get *-ised* / *-ized* (e.g. *Hellenize*, *Sinicize*, *Danicize*, *[Africanize](http://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/jan/24/africa-clinton)*) to most cultures or regions; others get *-ified*. You can also *Dutchify*, *Russify*, or *Frenchify* things where others might *Batavianize*, *Russianize*, or *Francize*. But be forewarned that words about assimilation often carry heavy political or historical meanings or overtones. Use terms like *Castillianize* or *Vietnamize* with care.

Comment: @BrianDonovan Can't resist that one but *allemadation* should certainly be *germanisation/germanisé(e)* by all accounts I've ever encountered in France. ;)

Comment: Also see http://english.stackexchange.com/a/192779/16052 .

Comment: Try searching for "add *le* to the front"... :)

Comment: The phenomenon itself may not be totally identical among languages, especially with French and the Academie Francaise having a long tradition of "guarding" the language. In French we have the origianally spelled *le weekend* which is pronounced in a way that no Englishman would recognize (whereas I suppose the French still feel its origin?), whereas in German we have *Keks* which is an exact (as can be)  phonetic copy of *cakes* and Germans are usually surprised about its English origin (and on the other hand people are surprised that *Handy* (with English pronunciation!) is not).

Answer (score 10):

*[Gallicize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gallicize)* is the direct analogue for *anglicize.* M-W further certifies *[germanize](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/germanize)* for German. No such luck for my conjecture *hispanicize,* and of course *italicize* means something quite different. As for the relevant hypernym, I am at a loss.

Comment: For the Germans, *teutonize* may provide a better parallel with *gallicize* in using classical roots, as with *hellenize* and *sinicize* (perhaps *lusitanize*?). AHD and CED both attest to *hispanicize*. *Italicize* derives from *italics*, not *Italy*, though *italics* of course is a reference to a style of writing that was associate with Italy. *Nipponize* and *hebraize* also appear in dictionaries, but appear to be rare.

Answer (score 2):

*OED* has *frenchize and frenchify; along with englishize* and *englishify*.

In the end, *-ize* and *-ify* are productive suffixes and you can come up with any verb for any country/language. Of course, some verbs will sound jarring ([niue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niue)ize?!) and some are probably never used before; but it doesn't mean you can't coin that word for your needs. Some verbs are more established because the culture of those countries are more influential (like England, France, Germany, Japan, Russia etc.) or the usage of the verb was more prevalent in the history.

The same thing applies to the languages also as some languages are more influential. *OED* lists the verb form of a lot of countries/nations/languages. I tried to list all the verbs (with *-ize* and *-ify* suffixes) related to nations or languages in *OED*:

- Italianize
- Czechize
- Polonize
- Scandinavianize
- Britannicize
- Russianize
- Japanize, Japonicize, Japonize
- Irishize
- Romanianize
- Scotize
- Indianize
- Englishize, Englishify, Englify, Anglicize, Anglicanize
- Canadianize
- Grecanize, Graecize, Hellenize, Greekize
- Hispanize, Hispaniolize, Spanishify, Spaniardize, Hispanicize
- Turkize, Turkify, Turkicize
- Frenchize, Frenchify, Gallicize
- Germanize, Teutonize
- Levantinize
- Syrianize
- Iranize, Iranicize
- Iraqize
- Asianize
- Sinicize, Sinify (for China/Chinese)
- Koreanize
- Malayanize
- Filipinize
- Australianize
- Africanize
- Zambianize
- Nigerianize
- Americanize
- Mexicanize

Comment: Productive suffixes are not suffixes that can be tacked onto any stem imaginable to produce an acceptable word. There needs to be some level of acceptance for a candidate word to be acceptable as a word. And _niueize_ hasn't enough currency to be accepted as a word.

Comment: Irishize wouldn't work because somebody would always start singing.

Comment: Prob'ly have the same issue with Spanishize.

Answer (score 1):

Here're the terms I found: 'Francize'(Canadian), 'Frenchify' and 'Gallicize' (as already mentioned)

Being a student of French, I always thought 'Frenchify' was the only term that existed. Now I know two more.

I haven't heard of any generic term for such adoption or "conversions" from one language to another.

Comment: For some reason"Frenchify" sounds like something you'd hear one of the Clampetts from *The Beverly Hillbillies* say.

Comment: Yeah, it might sound a little pejorative, but it exists in the dictionaries.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the hypernym is *languify*.

Comment: But that is not in either M-W or OED, though the latter has *languefy* meaning *make languid.*

Comment: @BrianDonovan It is in the Urban Dictionary. OP: consider adding some references.