# Is there a form of "Anglicize" for other countries, specifically Ireland?

Tags: anglicization

"Anglicize" carries the meaning of making someone or something English in form or character. However, is there a variation for this for other countries? Hence, as a foreigner living in Ireland, if my mannerisms and behaviour become more "Irish", can I say that I was "Irishcized"? How about other European countries, such as Spain, France, Poland?

Comment: [*...his name was set down in English on the programme, which, for the rest, consisted of a list of names which meant nothing to an English reader. Had the management been consistent, they would have **Erinised** all the names...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Erinised+all+the+names+of%22)

Comment: [*...the heritage that the Normans brought and which (like the Normans themselves) became **hibernified**, even **celtified** as time went on.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22became+hibernified%2C+even+celtified%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers those sound like good parts of an answer

Comment: @Mitch: I'm currently sitting on the fence re whether it's a duplicate or not. But leaning towards thinking it *is.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, well then a good answer there then. Either place.

Comment: @Mitch: I *almost* thought about appending a line ***Irish** → Erinise, Hibernify, Celtify* to the "possible dup" question text. But having scrolled through to find there's already an answer that covers many nationalities / languages, I thought that was probably a more suitable place. Perhaps the ideal solution is for [ermanen](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/247373/2637) to flag his answer "Community Wiki" as an encouragement for us to simply edit any and all future suggestions into that "master list".

Comment: Understand that some Danish Viking Normans from the time of William the Conquerer actually had Celtic paternity (I speak from first-hand experience). In other words, they were already Celtic before they even thought about invading England.

Answer (score 9):

The common way of coining such words in English is to take the Latin name of a region or country, drop the *a* from an *-ia* ending, and then attach an *-ise, -ize* suffix, more rarely *-ify*. Capitalization varies.

**Hibernia** (Ireland)

> An alternative answer is that common speech, however different from, even inferior to, the [*hibernicised*](https://books.google.de/books?id=lMPfo6bIzSQC&pg=PA65&dq=hibernicised&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwix8rqkrbfaAhWqFZoKHfC6AC8Q6AEINDAD) English on which Synge worked, is amenable to the metamorphoses of art.
>
> …observation «that to date the Irish have failed to claim ownership of [*Hibernified*](https://books.google.de/books?id=xp7ptrf5AMgC&pg=PA152&dq=hibernified&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjy_NXerbfaAhWybZoKHfVpAFkQ6AEIJDAA) English».

**Hispania** (Spain)

> Similarly, the fundamental objective of the Indians was the expulsion of the Spaniards and their allies, including the *[Hispanicised](https://books.google.de/books?id=tbQ1DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA86&dq=hispanicised&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiSmo_b77faAhXHCsAKHXROCCQQ6AEIPzAF)* Indians.
>
> After the Conquest, Spanish and [*Hispanified*](https://books.google.de/books?id=oqQhAQAAIAAJ&q=hispanified&dq=hispanified&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie4JzOqbfaAhXLbZoKHakcB7s4ChDoAQhMMAk) Indian chroniclers went back to the pyramids and questioned the defeated Mexicans who lived nearby about the history of Teotihuacan.

or, more rarely, the purely English formation with vowel reduction, more often found in older sources:

> The earliest settlers were buccaneers like Peter Wallace or Willis, whose name may have been [*Spanified*](https://books.google.de/books?id=vwETAQAAMAAJ&q=spanified&dq=spanified&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOzaeoqbfaAhXBJ5oKHdGiD5E4FBDoAQg1MAQ) as Belize.

**Germania** (Germany)

> The spelling used in diplomatic correspondence was often Spitzbergen, the [*Germanicized*](https://books.google.de/books?id=FO8sAAAAMAAJ&q=germanicized&dq=germanicized&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj2yP-hq7faAhVFJ5oKHbVnDMg4ChDoAQg-MAY) form, though incorrect.

but also a purely English form:

> Like many educated Estonians, he had [*Germanized*](https://books.google.de/books?id=blLUHcUkEIUC&pg=PA168&dq=germanized&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqjNDRrLfaAhWPOSwKHcn4Auk4FBDoAQgjMAA) his name, aspiring to join the local German establishment.

**Bohemia** (Czech Republic)

> During the 19th century, the Czech linguistic environment saw many, particularly German, names adopt a *[Bohemicized](http://docplayer.net/amp/34919507-The-wallenstein-portrait-gallery.html)* form, this custom lasting down to the present.

And another English coinage:

> Even though Masaryk always considered himself a Slovak and frequently emphasized his ethnic origin, his life and career in Prague had left him *“[Czechified](https://books.google.de/books?id=VN9uBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA60&dq=Czechified&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjS9LfH8LfaAhXkA5oKHRy3DT8Q6AEIPTAE)”* in the eyes of observers both at home and abroad.

**Polonia** (Poland)

> In Silesia in the early days Germans and Slavs often intermarried; many Germans [*polonicized*](https://books.google.de/books?id=qwmyAAAAIAAJ&q=polonicized&dq=polonicized&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjzjomorrfaAhWoK5oKHRhdC7YQ6AEINjAD) their names, and adopted the Polish language for everyday use.

**Gallia, Francia** (France)

> The words and expressions that are obviously Kreyol have been kept in Kreyol, changing Alexis's *[gallicized](https://books.google.de/books?id=41i-Qgnd-bcC&pg=PR47&dq=gallicized&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpl7rUx7faAhUiyKYKHRoCDXAQ6AEIUjAI)* orthography to standard Kreyol orthography.
>
> Meanwhile, the typical [*francicized*](https://books.google.de/books?id=UWA9DgAAQBAJ&pg=PA67&dq=francicized&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_oOrjrrfaAhUBMJoKHbv9BfoQ6AEILzAC) Muslim of 1954 who eagerly sought assimilation and was without any particular religious commitment had lost faith in France, joined the FLN and started turning up at the mosque for worship.

**Lusitania** (Portugal)

> Precisely that Cape Verdian Creole which is commonly said to be the most [*lusitanized*](https://books.google.de/books?id=dKMxRp5wfw4C&pg=PA462&dq=lusitanized&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjamtnlsLfaAhWKB5oKHSy6DDYQ6AEIJjAA) of all Portuguese-based Creoles, spoken in the culturally most lusitanized colonial setting.

Comment: I think gallicize is more common for France. It's also sounds better and is easier to pronounce.

Comment: @William: yes, I should add that one.

Comment: Note that, even though I find these 'right', all of these, while of differing degrees of 'official', are modern or deliberate constructions, neologisms, coinings. Mostly principled, but still up to argument. I could imagine 'teutonified' for German](https://www.google.com/search?q=teutonified), or ['eirified' for Irish](https://www.google.com/search?q=eirified+irish) or others.

Comment: I said _common_ way, i.e. from Latin, which doesn't exclude less common means of coining such words. _Teutonified_ doesn't even register on Google Books, but your regular Google search certainly shows usage.